# Passing QueryString ID from aspx page to winform textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, parameters

I am currently developing an aspx page that calls a winform. The issue at hand is passing the textbox variable from the web page, through the ProcessStartInfo event, to the winform textbox to retrieve an image. The viewer is from a vendor but is only applicable in a winform environment but the other information is coming from a CF page, to an href and to a nonfunctional web image viewer. Is what I am doing possible?

Aspx page code:

```
namespace ImageView
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void page Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = Request.QueryString["DKT_ID"].ToString();
            //TextBox2.Text = Request.QueryString["Name"].ToString();
            //TextBox3.Text = Request.QueryString["Age"].ToString();

ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\ImageViewer\ImageView.exe");
            psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;

            Process p = new Process();
            p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            p.Exited += new EventHandler(MyExited);
            p.StartInfo = psi;
            p.Start();
        }
```

Winform code:

```
        //SQL section for returning images
        #region "Images Query"

        ImageQuery = "SELECT isn AS isn ";
        ImageQuery += "FROM bc_bcc_document (NOLOCK) ";
        ImageQuery += "WHERE barcode_id = ? ";

        DataTable Imagetable = new DataTable();
        Imagetable.Columns.Add("ISN", typeof(Int32));
        DataRow Imagerows;

        //fills table with Images information
        OdbcCommand comd = new OdbcCommand(ImageQuery);

        string conne = "Dsn=XXXX; uid=XXXXX; pwd=XXXXXX";

        using (OdbcConnection connected = new OdbcConnection(conne))
        {
            comd.Connection = connected;
            connected.Open();

            comd.Parameters.AddWithValue("barcode_id", txtBarcode.Text);

            OdbcDataReader readar = comd.ExecuteReader();

            while (readar.Read())
            {
                isn = Convert.ToInt32(readar["isn"].ToString().TrimEnd());
                Imagerows = Imagetable.NewRow();
                Imagerows["ISN"] = isn;
            }
            readar.Close();
```

Comment: Interesting question, can't you pass it as args?

Comment: @Glitch100 thus is why I am inquiring. I've never had to do this so I am a little lost because it is the last portion needed to make this work as it should. Can you explain or show an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just pass the arguments from the web page like this

```
 var proc = new Process
 {
    EnableRaisingEvents = false,
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
       {
           UseShellExecute = false,
           FileName = path,
           Arguments = Request.QueryString["DKT_ID"].ToString()
       }
  };
  proc.Start();
```

and read the command line arguments in your WinForms application like this -

```
string singleArgument = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[1];
```

P.S - assuming that you are passing a single argument, that's why `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[1]` is used
because at [0]th position, you will get the path and [1]st position in the array would be useful to you.

Comment: where you have '@argument', is that relating to the textbox value or from the querystring of the URL? Like I stated previously, I've never done something like this so it is a little confusing. Thank you for the assistance as well.

Comment: @argument is nothing but a string that you can pass from your web page. So, from the winforms application, just call Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() from any form to get the passed argument. Also i have modified my answer. Please check that for reference.

Comment: in the winform, I am calling a textbox in a query to retrieve the image. I used `txtBarcode.Text =  singleArgument` but with no results. That is why I am needing to grab the DKT_ID from the URL and pass to the winform.

Comment: Please be more precise while asking questions. Your question stated "Passing QueryString ID from aspx page to winform textbox". So, i answered same that how you can pass your QueryString ID - "DKT_ID" to the command line arguments and you can get that in your textbox as textBarCode.Text = Environment.GetCommandLineArguments[1];
If still it does not work, then try to debug by putting breakpoints and figure out that are you passing the arguments correctly or not.

Comment: figured it out. Sorry about that. Thank you for your assistance!! Everything worked out great! so if I have 2 more parameters, I just add the next two the same way?

Comment: Yes, if you have any more number of parameters, Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() method will give you a string array of all the arguments out of which the first one i.e [0] will give you the file path and other elements of the array will give you the command line parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use ClickOnce? I think could be interesting, once if your client doesnt have that application installed, clickOnce will do install before start the application.

And you can pass args also.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172242(v=vs.110).aspx